Where do I compute/specify error variance in SEM all-item parceling approach?
I am a newbie to SEM and lavaan. I created a model for which I need to run an SEM. Due to extremely small sample size and several model parameters, I need to go for the all-item parcel approach for SEM with ML estimation, although I know parceling is controversial.
Prior literature suggests that I need to compute error variance if I am parceling all items for a factor.

Interestingly, the four studies cited here as examples of the all-item-parcel approach utilized
somewhat different equations to compute the error variance (θε). Whereas Holbert (2005) and Theiss
and Solomon (2006) used Bollen’s (1989) procedure (i.e., θε = [1 − α] × s2), the authors of the other
two studies modified the equation: Dillard and Shen (2005) fixed the error variance of each construct
to be “1 − α2 times its variance” (p. 156) (i.e., θε = [1 − α2] × s2); on the other hand, in the Pfau et al.
(2004, p. 341) study, “error terms were set at each variable’s variance times one minus the square root
of the reliability estimate for the variable” (i.e., θε = [1 − α1/2] × s2). Given that α ≤ 1.0 and s2 > 0,
squaring alpha inflates the set error variance whereas taking the square root of alpha makes it smaller
in comparison with Bollen’s original formula. All these authors cited Bollen as the source for the
computational procedure.
(Matsunaga, 2014; DOI: 10.1080/19312450802458935)

My question is, how and where do I specify/compute this error variance while using lavaan in R? I came up with the following syntax, is it correct (especially by using ~~)? Error variances have been calculated by: θε = [1 − α] × s2
model <- '
  Institutional_Support =~ 1*INSPT_COMP
  Lesson_Preparation_Time =~ 1*LPT_COMP
  Access_Use_Technology =~ 1*TECH_COMP
  Self_Efficacy =~ 1*SEFF_COMP
  Orchestration_Load =~ 1*TLX_COMP

  # Structural model: Experience with SHT as an observed variable
  Orchestration_Load ~ Institutional_Support + Lesson_Preparation_Time + EXP1

  # Specify fixed variances for each parcel
  INSPT_COMP ~~ error_variances_INSPT
  LPT_COMP ~~ error_variances_LPT
  TECH_COMP ~~ error_variances_TECH
  SEFF_COMP ~~ error_variances_SEFF
  TLX_COMP ~~ error_variances_TLX
'

# Fit the SEM model using ML estimator and bootstrap standard errors
fit_ml <- sem(
  model,
  data = my_data,
  estimator = "ML",
  se = "bootstrap",    # Use bootstrap standard errors
  bootstrap = 1000     # Number of bootstrap samples
)

'''
